# Capybara 'within' scope across multiple tests

Tags: rspec, capybara

Is it possible to define a Capybara scope that spans multiple tests (in RSpec)?

For example, I'd like to turn this:

```
it 'has two things' do
  within('.some-div') do
    expect(page).to have_text('foo')
    expect(page).to have_text('bar')
  end
end
```

into this:

```
context 'with two things' do
  before :each do
    within('.some-div') # pseudo-code - this doesn't work
  end

  it 'has foo' do
    expect(page).to have_text('foo')
  end

  it 'has bar' do
    expect(page).to have_text('bar')
  end
end
```

I tried using an `around` block like this:

```
around :each do |example|
  within('.some-div') do
    example.run
  end
end
```

While that parses and runs, it doesn't actually apply the `within` scope to the example.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
before :each do
  @section = page.find('.some-div')
end

it 'has foo' do
  expect(@section).to have_text('foo')
end

it 'has bar' do
  expect(@section).to have_text('bar')
end
```